# Mongoose insertMany ignores unique:true

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('connected');

  let DocumentSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: { type: String, unique: true } });
  let Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema, 'documents');

  const docs = [{ name: 'd1' }, { name: 'd1' }, { name: 'd2' }, { name: 'd3' }];
  Document.insertMany(docs, (err, docs) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log('Documents inserted', docs.length);
      }
  });
});
```

[image]

InsertMany method will add all the objects duplicating them. I cannot find the problem here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It should be working, did you check on DB to see what type of index `name` holds as of now ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. When defining the schema you must specify index:true. The documentation stated that if unique:true index is optional. It seems it is not so.

```
let DocumentSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: { type: String, unique: true, index: true } });
```